# Deleting certain lines from Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I was just wondering is there anyway of removing the first two lines after every line break? If so how will i be able to do this? I  have alot of information and not alot of time!

Also is there anyway of deleting any information inside a bracket, the information inside the bracket is always different. :/

Comment: Seriously, switch to vim and these tasks will be trivial. The second one would be three keystrokes.

Comment: Look up regex (although, if you have to match nested brackets they aren't usually a good tool for the job).

Comment: @timgeb: although I'm a heavy vim user, almost any decent text editor (including Notepad++) provide some regex dialect.

Comment: @Matteo Italia of course, but why would you want to use a regex if you can press di]

Comment: What is a space break?

Comment: space break/ line break same thing ;)

Comment: @user3689025 space is " " while line break is "\n". Totally different things! You can use "Find & replace" functionality: replace `\n\n\n` with `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way seems to be this:

- You can search for (and replace) line endings `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`, depending on your case.

If that does not fit your case, extend it by:

- Do a search that leads you to the first occurrence
- Record a macro using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, let it end with <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Play the macro using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> until you find no more occurences

Additional hint: An empty line is an empty block of text surrounded by two linebreaks, e.g. `\r\n\r\n`. Note that first/last line may need special care.

Comment: any tips on how to remove anything which has a bracket around it please?

Comment: @user3689025 Spend some time learning RegEx.  This isn't a snarky answer like "figure it out on your own", but an encouragement to empower yourself with it.  It is something that will continue in its usefulness for years and years to come.

Comment: ive already tried looking for tutorials on how to and some explanations on what \r is and stuff but i really cant find anything

Comment: Notepad++ has this nice feature "View/Show Symbol/Show all" which shows you control chars, like for example line breaks. As a rule of thumb, on Windows it's probably `\r\n`, on Linux `\n`, on a Mac maybe `\r`.

Comment: "*any tips on how to remove anything which has a bracket around it please?*" - how about including a sample into your question?

Comment: theyre just words (orange) or (blue) or (table)

Just stuff like that